# Using another's text number to commit ongoing fraud

Tags: spoofing, sms, fraud

Some Vietnamese refugee families have been Bitcoin defrauded by someone using an 805 text number.  Lookups say it belongs to a party in Tennessee. I want to know if it is possible that scammers in Asia, for example, could use that number to commit the fraud without the Tennessee party knowing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Could be SMS spoofing, hacker could be anywhere but just appearing as a random phone number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing

Or it could be an online SMS service which now owns a number previously held by a party in the US.  Searching for a phone number in an engine can be out of date.